# Model averaging - models with different covariates

Tags: r, model, mean

I have run models using negative binomial `glm.nb()` in R and have 3 top models with really close AIC (<2). I was thinking about doing a model averaging using MuMIn package.
My problem is to know how to handle my covariates. In fact my three models do not have the exact same set of variables.

```
M1 <- Response_variable ~ Cov1+Cov2 
M2 <- Response_variable ~ Cov2:Cov3
M3 <- Response_variable ~ Cov1+Cov2+Cov3
```

How can I average coefficients if the covariates are not in all the models? Do I have to add "0" to my models?

> I tried using summary((model.avg(candidate models)) and modavg.glm()
>   but neither of those commands seems to want to compute my estimates
>   because my models are negative binomial. Although when I read the
>   MuMIn's pdf it said that glm.nb was supported by model.avg. Is there
>   somthing else that I should write on the command?

Comment: Why not average predicted values? Why do you have to average coefficients?

Comment: Can you explain what it means when you say "covariates are not in all the models"?  What is your domain and range?  What, in a generic sense, are your analytic models?  An R^2 is a ratio of covariances, so if you can fit a model then there are variances between the analytic and the actual.  I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: By "covariates are not in all the models" I mean that between the three top models one covariate could be in one of the three but not in the other, or an interaction for example. I was wondering if the model averaging command in R would average my coefficients without me having to add a 0 coefficient when some of the variables are not in one of the models. I don't know if I am being clear...I am running a count response variable without zeros and my covariates are continuous except for one categorical with two levels.

Comment: Consider writing each model with *all* of the covariates in it ($X_k$), but with a 0-1 indicator variable ($I_k$) in front to show whether the term is present. Thinking of it that way, you would average the $I_k \beta_k$ across models, which is the average effect of each variable on each model. (I agree with @Analyst that it usually makes more sense to average predictions, but in some situations you want to consider average impact of predictors)